# Error installing Arch on LUKS-encrypted ZFS root: `/sbin/init does not exist`

Tags: arch-linux, luks, zfs, initramfs, dm-crypt

I have *almost* successfully installed Arch Linux on a LUKS-encrypted disk with a ZFS root.

I can get the password prompt to decrypt the LUKS volume, but the next step with loading the installed system from the ZFS pool is not working.

I get the following error immediately after decrypting:

```
Starting version 246.6-1-arch 

A password is required to access the archcrypt1 volume: 
Enter passphrase for /dev/disk/by-id/ata-Samsung_etc_etc_etc: 
ERROR: device ' ZFS=zroot/ROOT/default' not found. Skipping fsck.
no pools available to import 
ERROR: Root device mounted successfully, but /sbin/init does not exist. 
Bailing out, you are on your own. Good luck.

sh: can't access tty: Job control turned off 
[rootfs ]#
```

Any suggestions?  I feel like I'm so close to the finish line!

### Additional info:

The header/GRUB are on a USB stick:

- **/dev/sda**

  Internal SSD

  - LUKS container *archcrypt*

    - zpool *zroot* (containing installed Arch system)
- **/dev/sdb**

  USB drive

  - */dev/sdb1*

    1M BIOS boot
  - */dev/sdb2*

    512MB boot with GRUB, header
  - */dev/sdb3*

    Free space

`/etc/mkinitcpio.conf`

```
...
FILES=(/boot/header.img)
...
HOOKS=(base systemd autodetect keyboard keymap sd-vconsole modconf block sd-encrypt sd-lvm2 zfs filesystems fsck)
```

`/etc/crypttab.initramfs`

```
archcrypt1  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-Samsung_etc_etc_etc none    header=/boot/header.img
```

`grub.cfg`

```
...

menuentry 'Arch Linux' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-dbafe9793fadcd06' {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd4,gpt2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-ieee1275='ieee1275/(null)/sas/disk@0,gpt2' --hint-bios=hd4,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd4,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci4,gpt2  12345abcd-usb-stick-uuid-dcba54321
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 12345abcd-usb-stick-uuid-dcba54321
    fi
    echo    'Loading Linux linux ...'
    linux   /vmlinuz-linux cryptdevice=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-Samsung_etc_etc_etc:archcrypt1:header root=ZFS=zroot/ROOT/default rw loglevel=3 quiet
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /initramfs-linux.img
}

...
```

### Update #1:

Using the `zfs=zroot/ROOT/default` instead of `root=ZFS=zroot/ROOT/default` as per the [Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Install_Arch_Linux_on_ZFS#Booting_your_kernel_and_initrd_from_separate_boot_partition) results in the *exact* same error as above, only with

```
ERROR: device '' not found. Skipping fsck.
no pools available to import
```

### Update #2:

So the zpool `zroot` exists, and it can find it.  Is it a mounting problem?  Is it an fstab problem?
What am I missing here?

```
ERROR: device '' not found. Skipping fsck. 
no pools available to import 
ERROR: Failed to mount the real root device.
Bailing out, you are on your own. Good luck.

sh: can't access tty; job control turned off 
[rootfs ]# zfs list 
NAME                         USED      AVAIL       REFER      MOUNTPOINT 
zroot                        6.32G     443G        6.31G      legacy
zroot/ROOT                   192K      443G        96K        none 
zroot/ROOT/default           96K       443G        96K        none 
zroot/boot                   192K      443G        96K        legacy
zroot/boot/grub              96K       443G        96K        legacy
zroot/data                   192K      443G        96K        none 
zroot/data/home              96K       443G        96K        legacy
[rootfs ]# zpool status 
  pool: zroot
 state: ONLINE 
  scan: none requested 
config: 

        NAME                                                                          STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
         zroot                                                                        ONLINE       0     0     0
           dm-uuid-CRYPT-LUKS2-12345abcde54321vwxyz-archcrypt1                        ONLINE       0     0     0
errors: No known data errors
[rootfs ]#
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: some hooks are not compatible to systemd sd-* hooks, not sure if applies to zfs. root=ZFS= syntax is weird, don't see this in the wiki page, where does it come from? compare `mkinitcpio -H zfs`

Comment: Updated OP with what happens when I follow the wiki.  I *think* it comes from `ZPOOL_VDEV_NAME_PATH=1 grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` IIANM
Let me try `mkinitcpio -H zfs` and report back

Comment: I tried every permutation of the options in `mkinitcpio -H zfs`, no such luck.
I've updated my post again to display what everything looks like when I try to boot in.
This is killing me :-/

Comment: In that shell, can you check `cat /proc/cmdline` to see if parameters are actually set as expected?

Comment: Oh, also it says `USED 96K` for `zroot/ROOT/default`, whereas `zroot` (w/o ROOT/default` has `6.32G` used so maybe hence the message "mounted successful but /sbin/init does not exist", if files did not go into the intended zfs datasets

Comment: I deleted ROOT and ROOT/default because you're right, they don't contain anything.
Still the same problem though.
Any idea, any idea at all, what could be causing this?  I'm reading about the ZFS cachefile being the culprit (`ERROR: device '' not found. Skipping fsck.` _can_ be indicative of cachefile problems), but I just don't know.  A lot of these posts are 7 or more years old.